# Need some help for work. Some kind of christmas app or.....?

Tags: android, video, powerpoint

I mentioned to my boss that I could make a simple app (since we are given android phone and I have been learning to develop apps for them) for our department with useful telephone numbers and some basic information. I am not a pro app designer and I just started learning java/android 10 months ago in my spare time.

He seems excited, which is awesome (getting paid to write apps! woohoo!!) but he wants me to make a christmas app or something Android/smartphone/ipad related to send to customers. I have never developed for an ipad and I am no graphics designer or super duper programmer. I think he would be happy if I could make something like this:

1. An app internally distributed for Android (not too familiar with distribution and internal distribution). 
      -it seems much simpler to have an attachment that people can open in an email, but I think the idea of having an app is sexier
2. A powerpoint/video turned into an app. I have no experience making movies either. Is there a way to do this conveniently?

Basically, I need to make something that is nifty, uses some technology, and related to Christmas and my department. Any ideas?

Comment: it is better u post something you want so that people can answer to it. this is very abstract to reply anything.

Comment: yah it is. it is the wrong place for me to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word: don't.  If you have to ask, you probably can't get something done in the next 16 days that would delight your customers or show off your company in the best light.  You and your boss are off track on this one.

Comment: I think he basically wants to make a presentation that is better than a video or powerpoint. The video outdid the powerpoint and now he wants to outdo the video. I have no idea how to do that. Yes, off track, but I am checking to see if I can find some.

Comment: 16 days isn't much time.  A Google search would be better than asking  q question here.  Your real problem is that neither of you have much of an idea of what would be good to do.

Comment: I don't agree, google has no idea either. I do agree that I have no idea what to do. What's better than a video or powerpoint? Heck if I know. This is not a technical question and I should not have asked it here.

Comment: but I will let it roll around in the old noggen and ask around